# Do the git repository data structures use a canonical encoding?

Tags: python, git, dulwich

I'm using dulwich (a Python library) to access a git repository. When I use `get_object` to retrieve a commit, it has a number of attributes. One of those is `author`. When I retrieve this attribute, I get `bytes` and so the attribute is an an unknown encoding.

Is there an encoding I can safely assume? Does git translate all the metadata to utf-8 before storing it? If it doesn't, how do I know which encoding to use to decode the bytes?

Comment: Presumably the [current `i18n.commitEncoding` value](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_discussion) holds the correct value (default is UTF-8).

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Is the value of this config option propagated when you clone a repository, or do you have to remember to set it everywhere when you use a repository that has chosen an unusual encoding? If it's the latter, I'm going to start encoding everything I send to github as UTF-16 and watch the hilarity ensue.

Comment: I see that the commit object actually has a `encoding` header, copied from the `.git/config` setting. This is part of the `objects` data, so no hilarity, sorry.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I was noticing that, but it was `None` so I thought maybe it was meaningless. I guess maybe that means I can assume the default utf-8 for that particular commit.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Anyway, it looks like you've probably answered my question. So maybe you should format your comment as an answer and I can accept it. :-)

Comment: I'm doing a few additional tests; I've not been able to actually get my commit messages recoded to UTF-16 just yet..

Comment: @MartijnPieters - How about EBCDIC? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metadata is supposed to be encoded with the value set by the [`i18n.commitEncoding` config value](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_discussion); whenever a commit is created the current value is copied into the 'encoding' header on the object, if set; the default value is UTF-8.

That encoding value is available on Dulwitch objects as the '.encoding' attribute; if it is `None` then `i18n.commitEncoding` was not explicitly set and you can use UTF-8 as the default.

However! The actual data stored simply follows whatever bytes where handed to git and no re-coding takes place. The configuration value is purely informational. So you need to take into account that an incorrect codec was used, if you are going to use `object.encoding or 'utf8'` as the codec, use a sensible error handler or fallback strategy.

Comment: Thank you for doing the research necessary to figure this out. It's really disappointing to learn that no recoding is done. I should still try uploading an EBCDIC encoded repo that's honest with its encoding flag and see what GitHub does with it. ;-)