# Pasting UTF-8 copied text into github issue using Firefox, removes `\n`?

Tags: github

Since some time ago, when copying text from UTF-8 enabled terminal windows (on Windows!) into a GitHub issue (from Web browser), seem to remove the newlines (`\n`), causing all text to become one very long line.  This is a sudden and highly annoying issue, that I am not able to resolve.

I am sure sure the text as copied has not changed for years, since I have been using the same various terminals and Windows and pasting into all other places such as other programs and web sites, work fine.

Q: **Any idea what is going on?**

---

(I have also tried to find a way to report the issue to github, but since the MS acquisition, there is no longer a sensible way to report bugs!)

Other SO [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50827060/where-can-i-report-a-github-bug) have suggested to use [this](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues) repo for tracking, but still require you to send *email*.
<sub>(Who the heck uses emails for bug reporting these days!?)</sub>